# CSS 1px space between divs

Tags: html, css

I have made a pen showing the problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #fffeed;
}
#menu {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#menu > div {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#menu > div > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="menu">
      <div><a href="#">bio</a>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#">blog</a>
      </div>
      <div><a href="#">contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

If you check the menu with chrome developer tools, there is a 1px gap between every div.
I disabled the border, set margin and padding to 0 but I just would not go away.
Either I am to stupid to fix it or I don't know.
I tried out line-height: 0px; and vertical-align: top; but neihter of those worked for me.
I would greatly appreciate help,

Joel

Comment: Its white-space http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the whitespace you have in your markup and you'll be good

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="menu">
      <div><a href="#">bio</a>
      </div><div><a href="#">blog</a>
      </div><div><a href="#">contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Notice that the `<div>` starts right after the `</div>`

---

In the original markup, your line breaks and spaces between the `</div>` and the `<div>` causes text nodes at those points - http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/ gives you a pretty good idea of what's going on. Here's a snapshot of the section in question

[image]

Removing the whitespace gets rid of these text nodes.

---

These text nodes cause anonymous inline boxes (as per the visual formatting model - see https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#anonymous). These anonymous inline boxes inherit the properties of the containing block (i.e. #menu), which is why setting the `font-size` on the #menu to 0 (one of the options suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/360067) to the linked duplicate) would also get theoretically (and practically for most browsers) rid of the gap (with the addition of extra CSS to correct the font-size for the child divs)

Comment: Why not close this question as a dupe?

Comment: You have enough rep by now to recognize that this sort of question is asked quite often.  Make sure you do your due diligence and search to make sure questions are not duplicates before you answer them.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, did not intend to do that.
But can you explain to me why the space inbetween counts as whitespace?

Comment: @huhnmonster - I've added some more explanation to the answer. Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings thank you so much, that makes it a lot better to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the border-width to 0.

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```